# Cakephp read and write json files.

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, json

I am new to cakephp. I am trying to save json output as a file in webroot. I would also like read the file into a array.

I know we could output array as json object using json_encode($array). But I am stuck creating and reading json files into an array.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you sure that you want the file in webroot where it will be viewable by the general public?  The answer below shows the use of json_encode and json_decode which I think answers your question.

Comment: @Andy I know it is available, but I am not sure how to store it outside the webroot. Can I store it outside the webroot. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi, sure you can.  Depending on whether you plan to keep it or not you could store it in a subdirectory from your app/tmp/ directory.  Instead of using webroot as your base directory consider using TMP or something similar ( check out http://www.ossassociatesinc.com/Cakephp-manual/ch11s03.html ).  Just make sure that you chmod the directory to allow the Apache user rw access.  file_get_contents and file_put_contents don't need to access a file by URL and can take a path name (http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
//write
$json = '{"key":"value"}';
$file = new File('/path/to/file', true);
$file->write($json);
//read
$file = new File('/path/to/file');
$json = $file->read(true, 'r');
$json2array = json_decode($json);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.. You make it look simple.. I appreciate your help. I was wondering if we could save the file outside the webroot. Thanks.

Comment: You can save files anywhere inside php's root folder.

Answer (score 3):

> NOTE: This code belongs within a method in your Model or Controller.

Though cetver's answer is technically correct it's not very "cakey".

For CakePHP specifically I would do the following:

```
$json = '{"key":"value"}';
$json2 = json_encode(array("a" => 1, "b" => 2));
$path = APP . '[YOUR FOLDER NAME]' . DS . 'json';
$path2 = APP . '[YOUR FOLDER NAME]' . DS . 'json2';
$jsonFromFile;
$json2FromFile;

//write
if(!file_exists($path))
    file_put_contents($path, $json);

if(!file_exists($path2))
    file_put_contents($path2, $json2);

//read
if(!file_exists($path))
    $jsonFromFile = file_get_contents($path, true);
if(!file_exists($path2))
    $json2FromFile = file_get_contents($path2, true);
```

Explanation:

- $json is a standard pre-written JSON string, no confusion here
- $json2 shows you an example of how you can encode and array (or object) into a json string for your storage purposes
- $path utilizes some CakePHP constants. "APP" which gives you a resolvable path to your app folder & "DS" which serves as a system-safe directory separator
- We then check to make sure our files don't exist, at which point we use the method "file_put_contents" to write our files.

Happy coding.

Comment: Except the question was about how to READ a flat json file's contents. Additionally, for your answer to be "cakey", it should include a suggestion of doing this in either a controller, or as a datasource.

Comment: The OP offered no context as to where he was performing this logic, so why bother constraining my answer? The "cakey" aspect of my answer is making use of the Cake provided constants to ensure that the App is portal from environment to environment, irreverent of your configuration. You are correct in mentioning I missed the READ portion of my answer. I will update.

Comment: Cool. One catch, is that too many "CakePhp Developers" put code like this directly into view files, or copy-pasta across multiple controller methods. Solutions which do not also hint at Cake standards, are not really describing Cake solutions, but generic ones (that in this case uses Cake constants).

Comment: Note added. Let's put this to bed.